"Swiper.js: pauseOnMouseEnter causing delay equal to autoplay speed before pausing"
I'm currently using Swiper.js to create a slider with autoplay functionality. However, I'm encountering an issue with the pauseOnMouseEnter option where it causes a delay equal to the autoplay speed before pausing when the mouse enters the swiper element.
let SwiperBottom = new Swiper(".swiper--bottom", {
        spaceBetween: 0,
        centeredSlides: true,
        speed: 10000,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 1,
          reverseDirection: true,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
          pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
        },
        loop: true,
        loopedSlides: 8,
        slidesPerView: 8,
        allowTouchMove: false,
        breakpoints: {
          // when window width is >= 320px
          320: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 20,
          },
          480: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 30,
          },
          640: {
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 40,
          },
          720: {
            slidesPerView: 5,
            spaceBetween: 40,
          },
          1024: {
            slidesPerView: 5,
            spaceBetween: 40,
          },
          1200: {
            slidesPerView: 8,
            spaceBetween: 40,
          },
        },
      });

